# How to determine the most influential regressor in multiple-linear regression with multi-collinearity?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a multivariate regression model with 3 regressors and a response variable. All of them are numeric with same unit. But the 3 regressors are significantly correlated.

I need to find out which regressor contribute most/second to the response variable. 
I want to keep the regressors intact so I don't want to do something like PCA because each PC would be combination of all 3 regressors.

I tried a package in R called "relaimpo: Relative importance of regressors in linear models". It seems doing it suppose to do by giving back a relative importance matrix.

#

y is genome size while x1,x2 and x3 are components of the genome. So all the 4 variables have same unit. 
First few lines of my data set is like this:

> head(data)

```
  y    x1   x2    x3
```

1 81722 12102 6257 21494

2 79389 12046 5254 21955

3 81467 12759 6012 21811

4 77425 12333 3393 21899

5 78172 12741 5458 21464

My question is: which of the x contribute most to the variability of y?

####if use LM model without interaction, all x significant

> summary(lm(y~.,data))
>   Call:
>   lm(formula = y ~ ., data = data)
>   Residuals:
>       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
>   -1921.8  -561.1    79.9   516.0  2720.8 
>   Coefficients:
>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept) 5.094e+04  1.731e+03  29.422  < 2e-16 ***

x1          7.924e-01  9.186e-02   8.626 1.27e-09 ***

x2          1.192e+00  2.244e-01   5.313 9.61e-06 ***

### x3          5.847e-01  1.241e-01   4.710 5.28e-05 ***

Residual standard error: 1104 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9713,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9684
F-statistic:   338 on 3 and 30 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

############################################################

But x1, x2 and x3 are all significantly correlated:

> with(data,cor.test(x1,x2))

```
Pearson's product-moment correlation
```

data:  x1 and x2
t = 6.0258, df = 32, p-value = 1.007e-06
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5188266 0.8561576
sample estimates:
      cor
0.7290763

> with(data,cor.test(x3,x2))

```
Pearson's product-moment correlation
```

data:  x3 and x2
t = 10.463, df = 32, p-value = 7.411e-12
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7707769 0.9386146
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.8796592

> with(data,cor.test(x3,x1))

```
Pearson's product-moment correlation
```

data:  x3 and x1
t = 5.3758, df = 32, p-value = 6.657e-06
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4572082 0.8329872
sample estimates:
      cor
0.6888668

if I include interaction in the model, none of x significant

> summary(lm(y~x1*x2*x3,data))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 * x2 * x3, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-1664.4  -670.1   171.6   378.2  1745.1

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  4.667e+04  1.682e+04   2.775   0.0101 *
x1           5.139e-01  1.354e+00   0.380   0.7073
x2           1.316e+01  6.909e+00   1.904   0.0680 .
x3           5.592e-01  9.026e-01   0.620   0.5409
x1:x2       -8.294e-04  5.655e-04  -1.467   0.1544
x1:x3        3.576e-05  7.119e-05   0.502   0.6197
x2:x3       -5.360e-04  3.275e-04  -1.637   0.1138
x1:x2:x3     3.583e-08  2.641e-08   1.357   0.1865

Residual standard error: 910.1 on 26 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9831,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9785
F-statistic: 215.6 on 7 and 26 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

######### use "relaimpo" package on model without interaction

> rela1=calc.relimp(y~.,data,type = "lmg", rela = TRUE )
>   rela1
>   Response variable: y
>   Total response variance: 38531968
>   Analysis based on 34 observations

3 Regressors:
x1 x2 x3
Proportion of variance explained by model: 97.13%
Metrics are normalized to sum to 100% (rela=TRUE).

Relative importance metrics:

```
     lmg
```

x1 0.3241856
x2 0.3503318
x3 0.3254826

########## use "relaimpo" package on model with interaction

It only accept 2-variable interactions and "lmg" method:

> rela2=calc.relimp(y~x1+x2+x3+x1*x2+x1*x3+x2*x3,data,type = "lmg", rela = TRUE )
>   rela2
>   Response variable: y
>   Total response variance: 38531968
>   Analysis based on 34 observations

6 Regressors: 
x1 x2 x3 x1:x2 x1:x3 x2:x3
Proportion of variance explained by model: 98.19%
Metrics are normalized to sum to 100% (rela=TRUE).

Relative importance metrics:

```
          lmg
```

x1    0.320602721
x2    0.345668344
x3    0.322170263
x1:x2 0.001659694
x1:x3 0.008405496
x2:x3 0.001493482

#

From the relative importance metrics output, it seems x1,x2 and x3 have similar importance for y in this dataset. The result doesn't bother me but I would like to consult experts here whether there is major mistakes in the method.

My questions:
Is the multi-collinearity a big problem here? How can I deal with it while keep my xs?
Is there other ways to calculate relative importance in the model other than using this R package? 
Any advice of selecting the interaction terms?

Comment: Can you say a little more about your situation? What are your variables? What do you mean that they have the "same scale"? Can you paste in your regression output? (Also, I cannot parse the sentence, "It seems doing it suppose to do".)